# NLP - Determine whether a piece of text is talking about a given topic?

Tags: java, nlp, classification, stanford-nlp, information-retrieval

I have a Java application where I'm looking to determine in real time whether a given piece of text is talking about a topic supplied as a query.

Some techniques I've looked into for this are coreference detection with packages like open-nlp and Stanford-NLP coref detection, but these models take extremely long to load and don't seem practical in a production application environment. Is it possible to perform coreference analysis such that given a piece of text and a topic, I can get a boolean answer that the text is discussing the topic?

Other than document classification which requires a trained corpus, are there any other techniques that can help me achieve such a thing?

Comment: Generally, jargon words will give you a very strong indicator of topic (biology, chemistry) in the more academic texts. In simpler texts, look for repeated nouns and infer pronoun references.  It's extraordinarily easy to check if the topic is 'science', but much more difficult to see if the topic is 'the role of impermanence in world literature'. Your tool must be as intricate as the subject it measures. For example, who measures a pen in kilometres? It might as well be a chair because of the minuscule difference.

Comment: If you're working in english, you could try to use http://wordnet.princeton.edu/, which is a semantic lexicon. This way, you just have to see if there are words related to the subject you're looking for.

Comment: Any update on this? I am having the same problem. Need to determine a confidence that a given piece of text its talking about a topic that i would query.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest have a look at Weka. It is written in Java so will gel well with your environment, will be faster for your kind of requirement, has lots of tools and comes with a UI as well as API. If you are looking at unsupervised approach (that is one without any learning with pre-classified corpus), here is an interesting paper: http://www.newdesign.aclweb.org/anthology/C/C00/C00-1066.pdf

You can also search for "unsupervised text classification/ information retrieval" on Google. You will get lots of approaches. You can choose the one you find easiest.

Answer (score 0):

for each topic(if they are predefined) you can create list of terms and for each sentence check the cosine similarity of sentence and each topic list and show the most near topic to user